# ftp a tar file using python

Tags: python-2.7, ftp

I am trying to copy a file from remote server to my local machine using FTP and i have written a python script for it.:

```
import os
from ftplib import FTP
btsIp=raw_input("Enter the IP:")
try:
    ftp=FTP(btsIp,user='',passwd='',timeout=20)

except :
    print("FTP Connection failed")
sys.exit(1)
ftp.cwd('/store/slv_imt')
filenames=ftp.nlst()
for eachFile in filenames:
    localName=os.path.join('D:\Users\shaik-s\Documents\SLV_logs',eachFile)
    file=open(localName,'w')
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR' +  eachFile,file.write)
    file.close()
ftp.quit()
```

However, i am getting error, as command not understood:
    slv_imt_2016-07-13__00-00-34.tar

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python27/Scripts/ftp.py", line 16, in <module>
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR' +  eachFile,file.write)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 414, in retrbinary
    conn = self.transfercmd(cmd, rest)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 376, in transfercmd
    return self.ntransfercmd(cmd, rest)[0]
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 339, in ntransfercmd
    resp = self.sendcmd(cmd)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 249, in sendcmd
    return self.getresp()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\ftplib.py", line 224, in getresp
    raise error_perm, resp
error_perm: 500 'RETRSLV_IMT_2016-07-13__00-00-34.TAR': command not    understood.
```

Kindly help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the error, you need to add a space between "RETR" and "eachFile".

```
ftp.retrbinary('RETR %s'%eachFile, file.write)
```

But your code shows that you may encounter another problem, try to use the following cmd.

```
file = open(localName, 'wb')
```